# Comment linked "before" it was posted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, chat, time

I managed to travel to the future, by simply following a link in chat to the comment that was linked!  It was short lived, because I lost the advanced hour as soon as I went away from that page.

A comment was linked in chat, with the timestamp as "2 hours ago."

When I followed the link, the comment on the thread said it was posted "1 hour ago."

By the time I am posting this, the comment matches the chat, but they are [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16012280#16012280) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40176/should-one-say-the-blessing-borei-minei-besamim-on-essential-oils-made-exclusi#comment105931_40176).

Comment: YEZ has discovered the muon comment. Elusive, short-lived, but there. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real-time chat displays timestamps *in your local timezone*, based on your PC clock (as reported by your browser). Both comments on the site, and the chat transcript, use timestamps in UTC however, using the *server clock*. Relative times are displayed based on these two different clocks.

Next, the *relative time* (e.g. *2 hours ago*) is imprecise. Up until 1 hour and 59 minutes have passed, the relative time is displayed as *1 hour ago*.  If your computer clock is off by even a few seconds from the server clock (accounting for timezone differences), then relative time shown in chat could display *2 hours ago*, but the comment on the site, using the UTC clock of the server, will still display *1 hours ago* for a minute or so longer.

You could wait until just before 20:06 at which point you should see *3 hours ago* in chat a little earlier than the site where it'll be *2 hours ago* for perhaps a short while longer.

Note: The difference doesn't have to be big for this to happen; there could easily be a few seconds window, but you won't be able to detect differences smaller than, say, 100 seconds, from the achievements dialog.

Comment: They shouldn't be different amount of time with reference to now.  If one said 1:00 and the other said 2:00 it would be possible (although I do not live 1 hour away from UTC, so you would still be wrong).  But with reference to now, no matter where you are, an hour ago is an hour ago and 2 hours ago is 2 hours ago.

Comment: And my clock is 0 minutes (and several hours) off of the time in my achievement window.

Comment: @YEZ: and 1 hour and 58 minutes ago is **displayed** as 1 hour ago. So if your clock is a little fast and chat has determined it as 2 hours and 1 minute ago *in reference to your PC clock* then it'll show *2 hours ago* in chat. The site, using a **different** clock displays *1 hour ago* because it calculated 1 hour 59 instead.

Comment: @YEZ: and the seconds? The window is perhaps just very small. My point is that this isn't impossible, by a long shot.

Comment: It's craziness like this that makes me long for local times on *all* websites, not just SE ones. In the case of SE though, why are things designed this way? With all due respect to the devs, it seems really silly that they decided "hey, let's use different times for different parts of the sites". The only possible reason for this that comes to mind is different teams working on the different areas, but even then, there should be better collaboration between those teams to provide a seamless experience across the whole SE network. Anyway if anyone could please explain this, I'd appreciate it :)